# Custom validation of uniqueness failed on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I created custom validation for composite field `full_name` in model `contact`:

```
validate :full_name_must_be_unique

def full_name [last_name, first_name, mid_name].
       reject { |n| n.blank? }.join(' ') unless first_name.blank?
  nil
end

def full_name_must_be_unique
  contact = Contact.find_by(first_name: first_name, mid_name: mid_name, last_name: last_name)
  errors.add(:full_name, "must be unique") if contact.present?
end
```

Validation works on create and failed on update with "full_name must be unique" message. I suppose it's because of record existing in database and if I am not changing full name's attributes, validation fails.
How to fix problem?
Controller:

```
def update
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  if @contact.update(contact_params)
    redirect_to contacts_path, notice: "Contact updated."
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**
With help of @jonnynemonic and @MrYoshiji the final version of the validator is:

```
def full_name_must_be_unique
  contact = Contact.where(["first_name = ? and mid_name = ? and last_name = ? and id <> ?", first_name, mid_name, last_name, id])
  errors.add(:full_name, "must be unique") if contact.present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to denormalize the full name and then simply add the validates_uniqueness_of:

Migration:

```
add_column :contacts, :full_name, :string
```

Model:

```
before_validation -> {
  self.full_name = [last_name, first_name, mid_name].
       reject { |n| n.blank? }.join(' ') unless first_name.blank?
}

validates_uniqueness_of :full_name
```

Comment: the easier solution: `validates :first_name, uniqueness: { scope: [:mid_name, :last_name] }` (this will combine `first_name`, `mid_name` and `last_name` and make sure no record already matches these 3 attributes' value)

Comment: I agree completely, but more often than not, the user will be sorting on that field as well  :)

Comment: in this case (sorting on that field), it should be done by the SQL (so the sort is more efficient). Also, `full_name` should be defined as an instance method, and called by the `before_validation` and not set / defined inside the `before_validation` block. Your answer contains the correct logic but the implementation is not the best

Comment: Thanks for answers. But is it possible somehow to solve this case in my way, with custom validator? I tried use `changed?`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the current record from your query result. ensuring that the duplicity is detected in another record.

```
def full_name_must_be_unique
    contact = Contact.find_by(first_name: first_name, mid_name: mid_name, last_name: last_name)
    contact.each do |c| 
      if id != contact.id 
        errors.add(:full_name, "must be unique") if contact.present?
        return
      end
    end
end
```

you also can optimize your query and get the first duplicity and be sure it duplicity is another record diferent of current.

Also you can create an uniq index in database as prevention

Comment: replace the `find_by` with a regular `where` method and the code should work fine.